# SmartTarget/Fredhopper - "Rejecting faulty item"

Tags: 2011, smarttarget, fredhopper

Noticed in our xmlloader.log the following:

```
2014-04-04 18:34:13,076 INFO  [xmlloader] XmlLoaderApp.java:378 50108 There are no XML files in the incoming dirs. `6516' items were successfully added to the item store till now.  Waiting for input...
2014-04-04 18:45:19,998 INFO  [XML Parser Thread] DirectoryContentProvider.java:315 50104 File `20140404-184518-tcm_0-161882-66560_component_component.xml' is polled from directory content provider `batch -> batch'    
2014-04-04 18:45:19,998 WARN  [XML Parser Thread] FredhopperHandler.java:355 10499 Rejecting faulty item `tcm_72-137046-16_tcm_72-19919-32'. || Fredhopper@coaipstagep01:D:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS tags/fas-parent@79419
2014-04-04 18:45:19,998 INFO  [XML Parser Thread] DirectoryContentProvider.java:426 We have successfully moved processed file 20140404-184518-tcm_0-161882-66560_component_component.xml to D:\fredhopper\instance01\FAS\data\xml\processed\batch\20140404-174519998-20140404-184518-tcm_0-161882-66560_component_component.xml
```

Rather annoyingly the item has been rejected, but no reason why *and* it gets moved in the processed folder not the rejected one!

I need to find out why this item was rejected - I checked other logs but can see nothing.
It could be an Xml validation problem - is there a Fredhopper XSD I can test against?

There are about 30 - 40 attributes in the item - I could start to take them out one by one until it goes in - but does anyone have any other advice on how to track the root cause down?

Comment: you could try setting the debug level for the xmlloader to debug, this can be done by adding a log4j.xml to the config folder of your FH installation. I can't check the specific package to log for other then it starts with com.fredhopper

Comment: Glen - can you elaborate a little or point me to some docs - not a Java person! Is there any info about this on the Fredhopper Learning Centre?

Comment: > It could be an Xml validation problem - is there a Fredhopper XSD I can test against?
There is no XSD for the format, but there is a DTD. Fredhopper does report invalid/non-well-formed XML explicitly though.

Comment: OK - the answer in my instance was that we where sending an empty attribute. But, I'm happy to mark Gertjan's comment as the answer as it was the setting to debug in log4net that was the crucial piece that allowed us to discover this.

Answer (score 1):

The first things that comes to mind are the IDs having whitespaces, dashes, quotes, etc which are not allowed. 
Or an attribute has a different value in it then specified. (e.g.: Defined integer attribute but has a String or Float value in it)